# Unable to install angular cli ...packages are looking for funding

Tags: npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am getting below message while installing angular cli

**changed 209 packages, and audited 210 packages in 24s
26 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
found 0 vulnerabilities**

Comment: What you describe is not an error. Did you try the `ng` command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.